# How to get WordPerfect 5.1 working under Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, wordperfect

Wordperfect 5.1 (for DOS) doesn't work without modification under Vista.  How can I get it to work (as well as possible) under Windows Vista?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: the "modification" so it work part?

Comment: This question and your answer do not belong here, they are unrelated to programming.  Also, you should credit that post if you're not the original author, not copy and paste the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Run it inside [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/).** That should solve your problems.

Their emulation is quiet decent, they have solved problems with EMS/DOS4GW/whatever etc.

I think it should run any DOS application pretty much OK.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a Virual Machine running DOS.  You can download Virtual PC for free [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/downloads/virtualpc/default.mspx).  You will need a copy of DOS to do the install.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe DosBox does work. It works fine with most Dos Games and Programmes. It's free and still beeing improved http://www.dosbox.com/

Answer (score 0):

Also info at http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/wpdos/vista.html